# problem with highlighting single words with adobe reader in iPad

Tags: pdf, highlighting, adobe

It seems awful that I can't highlight an individual word in adobe reader in ipad. Selecting words are done randomly. In some cases, it does highlight an individual word whereas in other cases, it highlights a complete line. According to [this link](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1059965?tstart=0), the problem might come from the way Latex generates pdfs. I have two questions regarding this issue. First, is it true that Latex is the cause? If yes, is there any way to solve this problem? A snapshot for this problem has been taken from the aforementioned link,

[image]

Comment: It is not really LaTeX specifically. I believe it is just a matter of the interword space. If it is too small, the viewer gets confused and doesn't see the words as separate. If you increase the interword space, it should be fine. However, doing this and getting a typographically pleasing result is less easy. The best would be to pick a font with a larger interword space to begin with so that you don't have to either artificially increase it or curtail TeX's ability to make lines look nice by tweaking the spacing.

Comment: This isn't really iPad specific, either. It just sounds like the mobile viewer is worse than the standard versions at picking up word breaks.

Comment: @cfr, I've tried to zoom in where the space is big enough. This doesn't solve the problem. Another problem is that I only have the pdf. I can't modify the file. Since majority of academic papers use Latex, I'm not able to highlight the most important phrases.

Comment: I don't think zooming would make a difference, and the suggestion about altering the space obviously could only be implemented by the producer of the PDF and not by the reader. My only point was that I don't think this is about LaTeX *per se* - the viewer is just insufficiently sensitive to smaller spaces (unlike, say, the human eye). This can happen in other viewers, though the Adobe's iPad viewer sounds worse than most. Can you use another viewer?

Comment: @cfr, I've downloaded another pdf and the problem is gone. This means the pdf itself might be corrupted. At least now, I can say that the problem might not be from the app.

Comment: So is the problem solved? It is all going to depend on the spacing, as I understand it, so some PDFs will behave better than others. It doesn't mean the others are 'corrupted' or that there is anything wrong with them.

Comment: @cfr, some pdfs have no problems, other pdfs specially academic papers which are usually generated by Latex, the problem is exist.

Comment: Yes, I know. But that does not mean there is anything wrong with the PDFs which don't work. The viewer doesn't like the spacing they use. That is still the viewer's problem. Calling PDFs 'corrupt' because one viewer is insufficiently sensitive to interword spacing is nonsense. There's nothing wrong with the PDFs. If you can select individual words in other viewers, the problem is not with the PDF. (And even if you can't, the problem isn't *necessarily* with the PDF.) You can check the validity of PDFs, but I bet that's not the problem.